# How to close \Big( with an invisible bracket?

Tags: equations, brackets

When then opening and closing of a bracket are not on the same line, LaTeX demands 'invisible' brackets or it will get confused and not compile. Example:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    A = 5 & \left(  a + b + c + ...  \right. \\  % The '\right.' is invisible but needed to close the 'left)
          & \left. d + e + f \right)         
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I noticed that this behaviour doesn't work when instead of using `\left(` you use `\Big` (or any similar bracket size expression). The following doesn't compile:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    A = 5 & \Big(  a + b + c + ...  \right. 
          & \left. d + e + f \Big)       
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

It gives the following error:

```
 ? Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.20    A = 5 & \Big( a + b + c + ...  \right
                                            . \\
?
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: with `\Big(` (or better `\Bigl(` you do not need to close it: it is a self standing bracket

Comment: Ah thanks, that actually makes sense of course, as it's more a character of fixed size, rather than an intelligent variable object like `\left(`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle An answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `\Big(` (or better `\Bigl(` you do not need to close it: it is a self standing bracket.

`\left` `\right`  are different in that they need to see the intervening expression as a single math list in order to determine the size to stretch, which is why they can not span different cells in an `align`.